# Formatar latitude e longitude numérica em Javascript

Tags: javascript, number-format, coordenadas

Estou precisando colocar a quantidade de casas decimais na minha latitude e longitude; atualmente elas se encontram assim:

```
-50850080, -29361808
```

E gostaria que ficasse assim:

```
-50.850080, -29.361808
```

Só que tinha que ser algo válido, pois pode acontecer de ter apenas 1 casa decimal. Não sei como resolver isso ou se é possível.

Comment: Ponha a parte relevante do código para vermos como está montando o par de coordenadas. Supondo que sejam valores numéricos, em princípio é só dividir por 1000000, não?

Comment: fazer o que precisa é relativamente facil, o problema é que a longitude vai de -180 ate 180. Se voce tiver um numero -179361808, fica meio complicado para saber se é -179.361808 ou -17.9361808. Se as casas depois do ponto sempre forem 6 ai é tranquilo, mas a precisao pode variar se nao me engano.

Comment: Acho que você precisa dar mais detalhes do problema porque pode ser que não seja uma questão de colocar apenas o ponto decimal no lugar certo. Parece ser um problema de conversão/projeção de coordenadas.

Answer (score 0):

Vou dar uma de sobrinho e vou sugerir uma solução com plugin jQuery:

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

No bloco de exemplos, dê uma olhada na funcionalidade de "translate". Adaptando para as regras de longitude ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
$('input.longitude').mask('99Z.99999999', {
    translation: {
      'Z': {
        pattern: /[0-9]/,
        optional: true
      }
    }
});
```

Dessa forma, se o usuário inserir dois digitos e depois o ponto, a máscara não moverá o ponto de lugar. Mas é obrigatório que o usuário insira o ponto.

A quantidade de casas decimais fica a critério do projeto -- o Google Maps utiliza 8 casas após a virgula, mas, se eu não estiver enganado, o padrão de longitude pode ter até 13 digitos após o ponto.